# Making a dice game. Trying to get the loop to break as soon as one player reaches 100

Tags: c++, break

fairly new to c++. I'm to create a dice game that lets you set the number of sides to the die and the number of players. Everyone starts at 1 pt and the game ends as soon as someone hits 100 or more.

This is the code I have so far

```
int players = 5;
int playerPosition[players];
for(int i=0; i < players; i++)
{
    playerPosition[i] = 1;
}

for(int i = 0; i < players; i++)
{
    while(playerPosition[i] < 100)
    {
        int roll;
        for (int j = 0; j < players; j++)
        {
            roll = dieRoll(6);
            // dieRoll is a function I made to simulate a die roll
            playerPosition[j] += roll;
            cout << "Player " << j + 1 << " rolled a " << roll << " and is now in position " << playerPosition [j] << endl;

        }
    }

}
```

So at the moment, the output will print out each turn for each player fine. The problem is that it'll keep going until every player reaches >= 100. I have tried adding

```
if(playerPosition[i] >= 100)
{
   break;
}
```

In the for loop and in the while loop. They still don't work the way I want it to. Can you tell me what the problem may be?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you are fairly new to C++, know that you don't use arrays for such things. Use `std::vector` - it's the standard collection type of C++. Use arrays only when the particular need arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are rolling each player, one at a time, until they reach 100 points. You need to check if there is a player over 100 *each time you roll the dice*

One way you could do this would be to have a `bool gameOver` variable declared outside the outer for loop, with its value initially set to `false`. Every time you increment a players score, you can add the line

```
playerPosition[j] += roll;
gameOver = playerPosition[j] >= 100
```

Now, if you change your code to have the structure

```
while(!gameOver) {
for(int i = 0; i < players; i++) {
```

it should behave as intended. The full code thus becomes

```
int players = 5;
bool gameOver = false;
int playerPosition[players];
for(int i=0; i < players; i++) 
{
    playerPosition[i] = 1;
}

while(!gameOver) {
for(int i = 0; i < players; i++) {
    int roll;

        roll = dieRoll(6);
        // dieRoll is a function I made to simulate a die roll
        playerPosition[j] += roll;
        gameOver = playerPosition[j] >= 100
       if (gameOver)
       {
          break;
       }
        cout << "Player " << j + 1 << " rolled a " << roll << " and is now in position " << playerPosition [j] << endl;

    }
}

}
```

Comment: I apologize. I tried out the suggestion you gave me. It actually still doesn't work correctly. It keeps running until player 5 reaches 100. So even if the other players are already at 100+, it'll keep going until player 5 reaches the goal.

Comment: Please see my edit, you need to break out of the for loop once one player reaches 100.

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether the player exceeded a sum of 100 every time after his sum has increased:

```
int players = 5;
int playerPosition[players];
for(int i=0; i < players; i++)
{
    playerPosition[i] = 1;
}

while(true)
{
    int roll;
    for (int j = 0; j < players; j++)
    {
        roll = dieRoll(6);
        // dieRoll is a function I made to simulate a die roll
        playerPosition[j] += roll;
        cout << "Player " << j + 1 << " rolled a " << roll << " and is now in position " << playerPosition [j] << endl;

        if(playerPosition[j] >= 100)
        {
            return;
        }

    }
}
```